# Dismissing Calendar window

Tags: window, calendar

In Emacs 24.5.50.1, dismissing the `calendar` window with `calendar-exit` works fine when there is a single window. However, when the window is split, the `calendar` buffer disappears, but the window remains.

This is reproducible with `emacs -Q`:

[image]

Should this be considered a bug and reported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a `FIXME` comment in the code of that function for this very issue, so check and see if there's an existing bug logged for it, and if not then go ahead and report it.

```
;; FIXME: replace this cruft with the `quit-restore' window property
```

Edit: This exists as [bug #11140](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=11140).

The [most recent message](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=11140) suggests that the proposal has most likely been forgotten about, so you should certainly follow this up and see if you can get the change made.

Comment: I am displaying the calendar in the current frame, so `calendar-setup` is null and the code in question never gets run. Instead, it's the "else" form that matters. Changing `quit-windows-on` to `delete-windows-on` works fine.